# How to upload image to multiple folders using core php only?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have tried to upload image in multiple folders using following code but i have faced a problem is uploaded image showing black.

It's upload successfully in main folder but in thumbnail folder it's showing black.

Code

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);


$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    $originalsFolder = "uploads/"; //original photos only
    $thumbsFolder =   "thumbnails/";  //thumbnails only -- 150

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {    
        $fnam=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
        $q = "INSERT INTO testimage (id, image) VALUES (NULL, '".$fnam."')";
        $query = mysqli_query($con,$q);
        $file = $originalsFolder.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        createImageCopy($file, $thumbsFolder,  250);
    }
}
```

Following is callback function for thumbnail image

```
function createImageCopy($file, $folder, $newWidth){

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $imgRatio = $width/$height;
    $newHeight = $newWidth/$imgRatio;

    if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'] =="image/jpeg"){
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    }else if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'] == "image/png"){
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        $source = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    }

    if($newFileName = $folder.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']){
        imagejpeg($thumb,$newFileName,80);
    }else if($newFileName = $folder.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']){
        imagepng($thumb,$newFileName,8);
    }

    imagedestroy($source);
    imagedestroy($thumb);

}
```

HTML Code

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">

</form>
```

There 2 folders for upload image 
1) uploads ( It's working fine , uploaded image also display)
2) thumbnails (uploaded image successfully but `it's showing black image`)

I have tried many ways but could not found any way , if anybody know more about it then please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following function instead of `createImageCopy`

```
function create_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
}
```

And use this function as place of function `createImageCopy`

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {    
        $fnam=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
        $q = "INSERT INTO testimage (id, image) VALUES (NULL, '".$fnam."')";
        $query = mysqli_query($con,$q);
        $file = $originalsFolder.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $thumbsFolder =   "thumbnails/";  //thumbnails only -- 150
        $path_to_image_directory = $thumbsFolder . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        create_thumb($file, $path_to_image_directory, 150);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an exact copy of the same file then try using.

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
 {    
    $fnam=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    $q = "INSERT INTO testimage (id, image) VALUES (NULL, '".$fnam."')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    $file = $originalsFolder.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    copy($file,$thumbsFolder.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
 }
```

Comment: Using copy we upload on copy image of original size not upload thumbnail size.